# Create an artificial data

Tags: r, math

I have this issue to task on me and i dont know where to start.
The task is to create artificial data: Suppose that

[image]

We take that:

[image: image 2]

Let

[image: Xi1, Xi2]

denote a random vector (r.v.) having uniform distribution over [image: image 4].

now if the top part I can understand how can i uniformly distribute over Ii and generate 5 coppies

Answer (score 1):

To distribute uniformly, use `runif`. In this case over a 2d set call `runif` twice with the appropriate limits.

```
runif2d <- function(n, limits = list(a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, d = 1)){
  X1 <- runif(n, limits[[1]], limits[[2]])
  X2 <- runif(n, limits[[3]], limits[[4]])
  data.frame(X1, X2)
}

I1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 0, d = 1)
I2 <- list(a = -2, b = -1, c = 0, d = 1)
I3 <- list(a = -1.2, b = 1.2, c = 0.8, d = 2)

set.seed(1234)
runif2d(5, I1)
#           X1          X2
#[1,] 1.113703 0.640310605
#[2,] 1.622299 0.009495756
#[3,] 1.609275 0.232550506
#[4,] 1.623379 0.666083758
#[5,] 1.860915 0.514251141
```

A combination of `Map` and function `rbindlist` from CRAN package `data.table` can have all 3 results in one `data.table`.

```
res <- Map(runif2, list(I1, I2, I3), n = 500)
res <- data.table::rbindlist(res, idcol = "id")

head(res)
#   id       X1         X2
#1:  1 1.113703 0.66891915
#2:  1 1.622299 0.80104330
#3:  1 1.609275 0.85545589
#4:  1 1.623379 0.05013991
#5:  1 1.860915 0.67443409
#6:  1 1.640311 0.84589330
```

Comment: So instead of runif2d(5, I1) im using runf2d(500,I1) + runif2d(500,I2)? this might additional question but how do i append to get 3 sets?

Comment: @manydd You can create 3 sets then a `id` column, then `rbind` them together. Will edit.

Comment: Hmm, and what should i do if i want to union of the three sets described above?

Comment: @manydd You will have to be more specific. Are you looking for `?duplicated` or `?union`.

Comment: thanks for the response you are really helping me with this one. i need union